# Cartesian Product Notation for Encryption and Decryption

Tags: encryption, terminology, decryption, notation

I'm learning about encryption $(E)$ and decryption $(D)$ algorithms and am wondering what the following notation means, specifically the cartesian product for $E$ and $D$.

- $k$ represents key, $P$ represents plaintext, $*$ represents some length

$$k ∈ \{0,1\}^l$$
$$P ∈ \{0,1\}^m$$
$$E: \{0,1\}^l × \{0,1\}^m → \{0,1\}^*$$
$$D: \{0,1\}^l × \{0,1\}^* → \{0,1\}^m$$

My understanding is that $k$ is a key randomly chosen from the set of all length $l$ bitstrings, and $P$ is a plaintext chosen from the set of all length $m$ bitstrings. I am confused about about $E$ and $D$, shouldn't the resulting ciphertext be $\{0,1\}^{l+m}$ rather than $\{0,1\}^*$ from the rules of multiplying two cartesian sets? Also, how does multiplying $\{0,1\}^{l}$ by $\{0,1\}^{*}$ result in $\{0,1\}^{m}$? I think it should be $\{0,1\}^{1+*}$.

For example $\{0,1\}×\{0,1\}=\{0,1\}^2$, so shouldn't this rule apply to $E$ and $D$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a function mapping notation. A Cartesian product doesn't mean that the map is multiplication. The encryption map $E$ is from the space $\cal K \times \cal M$ to the space $C$. So we have a map defined for each fixed key $K\in \{0,1\}^l$ and each each fixed message $M \in \{0,1\}^l$ to some ciphertext $C\in \{0,1\}^\ast.$

In words, for each fixed $l$ bit key, we have a well defined encryption map $E_K$ from $m$ bit plaintexts to arbitrary length binary string ciphertexts.

Comment: To be honest, $\}^*$ is one of the worst choices since the [Kleene star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star)

Comment: $\{0,1\}^*$ **is** a Kleene star (and it is wonderful)!